# How can I use Ruby regular expressions to search for a path and replace it?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a python script:

speaking_to_sublime.py

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class SpeakingToSublime(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        self.window.run_command("advanced_new_file_new",{"initial_path": "/Users/max/test/test2/"})
```

and I'm trying to write a ruby script that does the following:

```
desired_path = "/some/path/i/want/to/go/"
# read speaking_to_sublime.py
# parse through it and store as a string
# store contents of speaking_to_sublime.py in here
speaking_to_sublime_string = ""
# use regular expressions to somehow replace:
# "/Users/max/test/test2/" with desired_path
# write speak_to_sublime_string to speaking_to_sublime.py
```

I can figure out how to read and write to a file with ruby, but how do I use regular expressions to get to `"/Users/max/test/test2/"` and replace it with `"/some/path/i/want/to/go/"`?

Comment: Why not just change the Python script to accept an argument for the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to modify the python script because I wasn't sure how to pass arguments to sublime from the command line. As a workaround I was going to make a custom plugin and change the "arguments" by writing them to a file right before I called the command using sublime from the command. It sounds roundabout but I didn't know about [escaping the quotes](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/is-there-any-applescript-or-literally-any-language-support-for-accessing-the-python-console-from-outside-sublime/19930/10) when you pass arguments from the sublime cli yet. I actually haven't testing if it would work yet, but for anyone who is interested the appropriate regex can can found [on rubular](http://rubular.com/r/iCSTL8hX4Y):

```
re = /"initial_path": "(.+)"/
```

the reason why I was trying to use regexs was because the path would be changing all the time since I was essentially planning to re-write the plugin every time it was called. I learned how to do it after watching a wonderful talk by [Nell Shamrell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfwS4ibJFDw)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is what you're trying to do?

```
python_file_path = 'path/to/speaking_to_sublime.py'
text             = File.read(python_file_path)
path_to_replace  = "/Users/max/test/test2/"
desired_path     = "/some/path/i/want/to/go/"

new_text = text.gsub(path_to_replace, desired_path)

File.open(python_file_path, "w") {|file| file.write(new_contents) }
```

You don't need a regular expression to replace direct text, `gsub` can accept a string to do the same thing, with better performance. If you insist on using a regex, you can use `path_to_replace = /\/Users\/max\/test\/test2\//`